# Rspec: implicitly defined subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

[Rspec implicitly defined subject documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) says:

> While the examples below demonstrate how subject can be used as a
>   user-facing concept, we recommend that you reserve it for support of
>   custom matchers and/or extension libraries that hide its use from
>   examples.

Does it mean, that I should try to never call "subject." directly in my specs? If yes, what should I use instead as a subject object?

Answer (score 3):

Compare these 2 examples:

```
describe "User" do
  subject { User.new(age: 42) }
  specify { subject.age.should == 42 }
  its(:age) { should == 42 }
end

describe "User" do
  let(:user) { User.new(age: 42) }
  specify { user.age.should == 42 }
end
```

**UPDATE**

There is a cool feature in Rspec - named subject:

Here is an [example](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/) from David Chelimsky:

```
describe CheckingAccount, "with a non-zero starting balance" do
  subject(:account) { CheckingAccount.new(Money.new(50, :USD)) }
  it { should_not be_overdrawn }
  it "has a balance equal to the starting balance" do
    account.balance.should eq(Money.new(50, :USD))
  end
end
```

When you use `user` instead of a `subject` it's more readable (IMHO).
But `subject` lets you use nice extension `its(:age)`.

Comment: You can now do `subject(:user)` in this case for the best of both worlds.

Comment: When to use `let` and when `subject`?